# Google query from terminal

Tags: command-line, search, google

Is there a way to launch a google query from the terminal? Like starting up google (as in `firefox www.google.com`) but with a search query? It would be nice to not have to install any extra programs and have single command to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
browser google.com/search?q=query
```

Where `browser` is the desired web browser.

Comment: You are welcome. I'd suggest asking at superuser.com next time since this is not very Ubuntu-related.

Answer (score 3):

You can add next function in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
function google { 
     Q="$@"; 
     GOOG_URL='https://www.google.com/search?q=';
     stream=$(exo-open "${GOOG_URL}${Q//\ /+}" | grep -oP '\/url\?q=.+?&amp' | sed 's|/url?q=||; s|&amp||'); 
     echo -e "${stream//\%/\x}"; 
}
```

Next, when you open a terminal you can run:

```
google query to search
```

or

```
google query to search &
```

to open in background your default browser at [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) including the search query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little script I use for exactly that with chrome:

```
#!/bin/bash -

FLAG="-i"
INCOG=""

if [ x"$1" == x"$FLAG" ]
then
        INCOG="--incognito"
        shift
fi


QUERY=$(echo "$*" | sed 's/+/%2b/g' | sed 's/#/%23/g' | tr -s ' ' '+')

nohup /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome $INCOG \-url www.google.com\/search\?sourceid\=chrome\&ie\=UTF\-8\&q\=$QUERY > /dev/null 2>&1 &
exit
```

I've included some html character replacement for  # and + so I can search for c# and c++ when I need to - more could easily be added to suit your needs. I also have a -i option for the script to launch in incognito mode. I'm sure this could be adapted to firefox, but I don't use firefox.